# DevDemon Updater: An upload error occured. CODE: 1

Tags: devdemon-updater

While uploading EE 2.9.0 zip file, Updater (v3.2.14) is throwing following error:
"An upload error occured. CODE: 1"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Current EE install is v2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying your PHP Maximum Upload Size and PHP Max Post Size is smaller then file you are uploading. We provide a listing of your max sizes on the Upload page. Make sure they are higher then the file you are uploading.